# Ubuntu Touch phone dialler settings

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When I start to enter a number into my phone dialler, I was hoping for it to show a selection of all the matching numbers in my address book/recent calls. Then for the list to keep on getting smaller the more numbers I enter, until the number of the person I want to call is displayed.

This way, it would prevent me from having to go into my address book all the time that I needed to make a call to someone.

Is there a setting that I can turn on to enable this functionality?

Comment: This is how it works in the messaging "To" field and it looks good. Just what I want and need to find the person I want to message. If this logic could be applied to the phone dialler screen, it would be a great improvement and a great usability feature.

Comment: This sounds indeed useful, but seems not yet to be possible. Why not opening a feature request?

Comment: Cheers, I had not thought of that. Think I might as it sure would be a nice and useful addition to the phone.

Comment: There's already a reported bug: http://pad.lv/1449691
Also another interesting feature request: http://pad.lv/1474435

Comment: Thanks for the bug numbers pomsky. The second bug is the one that this post is related too. Cheers.